# Laravel Backpack List function not working

Tags: php, laravel, crud

When I load the page, it gives me an error and tells me to reload.
However, when I add data to the database it works properly.
So, basically my list function isn't working and I don't know why.
I checked for typos, it can't be something like updating,  because of all my other CRUD's work fine with the same method.

**Controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\ProjectRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class ProjectCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class ProjectCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Project');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/project');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('project', 'projects');
    }

    protected function setupListOperation()
    {      
        $this->crud->setColumns([
            'name' => 'status', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Status'
        ]);
        $this->crud->setColumns([
            'name' => 'topic', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Topic'
        ]);
        $this->crud->setColumns([
            'name' => 'leader', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Leader'
        ]);
        $this->crud->setColumns([
            'name' => 'email', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Name'
        ]);
        $this->crud->setColumns([
            'name' => 'tags', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Tags'
        ]);
    }

    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->setValidation(ProjectRequest::class);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'status', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Status'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'topic', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Topic'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'leader', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Leader'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'email', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Name'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'tags', 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'label' => 'Tags'
        ]);
    }

    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('create');

        // execute the FormRequest authorization and validation, if one is required
        $request = $this->crud->validateRequest();

        // insert item in the db
        $item = $this->crud->create($this->crud->getStrippedSaveRequest());
        $this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->entry = $item;

        // show a success message
        \Alert::success(trans('backpack::crud.insert_success'))->flash();

        // save the redirect choice for next time
        $this->crud->setSaveAction();

        return $this->crud->performSaveAction($item->getKey());
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'projects';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['project_id'];
    protected $fillable = ['topic', 'status', 'leader', 'email', 'tags'];

    // protected $fillable = [];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SCOPES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ACCESSORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | MUTATORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
}
```

**Request:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'topic' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'status' => '',
            'leader' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|min:5|max:255',            
            'tags' => 'required|min:5|max:255'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error
Error loading the page, please refresh the page.

Comment: can you please check your browser network tab? you will get search request response. the response will sow you the error message??

Comment: "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `projects` order by `id` desc limit 10)",
Checked the table in the database, and found it the id is called project_id there,

Comment: fixed it by using     protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';

Answer (score 0):

protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';

Database had project_id instead of just id, so this should work.